# Excel Formula Needed for Daily and Monthly Prodution

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help configuring a formula for running total. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but let's see! Say I have two columns- one labeled "daily production" and the other "monthly production". Is there a way for the daily production to update the monthly production column each time there is a number put in without having more columns? For example, if 200 was put in a cell in the daily production column, the monthly production would be updated to 200. Then the next day, say we do 300. We update the daily production cell from 200 to 300, then monthly production would be 500. Is this a possible formula?

Comment: You want to change the same cell and have the second "Remember" the previous value and add the new value from that cell?  No, this is not possible with formula, you will need vba in a Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: Hi @Alexis, if you are looking for Summary sort of output,, one is what below posted by `#Yury Suturin`, and another should, use `Daily Inputs` and go for `Group & SubTotal`, group on `Month` and get Subtotal for `Value Entry`. BUT what you have described in your post above is `RUNNING SUM` and yes it's possible,, if U are looking for it, just confirm through comments, will help us to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with vba as Scott Craner described, you can try to do kind of similar thing with Smart Tables. The good thing about those tables is they adjust automatically so the formulas are adjusted as well

[image: See example]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't save and calculate previous data by formula alone.

I recommend you use PivotTable, you just need to simply record the daily production, the PivotTable monthly production data can be automatically updated.

[image]